# Asp.Net WebForms SSRS ReportViewer ShowFindControls Issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

ReportViewer control not showing Find Widget after upgrading Microsoft.ReportViewer from 11 to 15 version.This problem occurs if ShowExportControls is true. Both ShowExportControls and ShowFindControls are true. How can I fix this ?

Here is screenshots for old and new versions.

Old:

[image]

New:

[image]

Code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" ShowExportControls="true" ShowFindControls="true"/>
```

Comment: Please include the code and options you used for the embedded report viewer control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same exact issue. After inspecting the css code, I found that the class for the "ShowfindControls" is hidden

> **"style="vertical-align: top; display:none;"**

while it should be

> **"style="vertical-align: top; display:inline-block;"**

So, actually you could use Jquery to change the css and show this div, but the I found out that my reportviewer width was not enough. So, just increase the width of the ReportViewer to 1200 for example and it will work. You could also try to disable other toolbars and show only Finder and it will work. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: You are right it is about width. Increasing the width solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am so glad that it helped. Good luck in your project.